# Have a mac acccess apache through localhost on a windows environment

Tags: network, windows, apache

Some people on my network use Mac so I have to configure my local server for them to access it. I installed Apache on my Windows Vista PC and you can access it from any other WINDOWS computer on the network just by entering localhost on the address bar. But you cant do that on a Mac for some reason.

The only way I know is to enter the local IP of the server machine but since it changes every time is really not practical at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: `localhost` is exactly that, the *local* computer (aka the one you are sitting in front of). So if accessing `localhost` in a browswe on Computer1 gives you access to an Apache webserver running on Computer2 something is rather strange on your network. Either way, the problems seems to be more related to cross-system network setup, running a DNS on Windows, assigning fixed addresses in DHCP etc than to anything directly related to Apple products or their use, so the Superuser site might be the better place to ask.

Comment: I think you need primer on networking, specifically [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with Mac vs. PC; it's a Windows Server network one. Even still, it's not an issue of deficiency in Windows Server or Apache, but rather one of knowledge of network administration.

Resolving hostnames in a multi-platform, networking environment is basic. It wasn't even hard to do 16 years ago, when I first encountered this issue as the sole Mac user in my company.

I do not know, but suspect, that you need an IP address to the DNS server, which you can then manually supply through the Networking pane in System Preferences (or some such). This, though, is just a guess, but I doubt I'm that far off.

As far as whether the Mac is worse or better than Windows on any networking issue is a ridiculous argument to have, as anything networking-related on the Mac is older than the Mac itself (and therefore not really Apple's own machination), and any such thing found in Windows is probably a derivative of the same thing found on Mac.

This argument could have been had in the days of AppleTalk and what-not, but that's been over since 1999.